# Insert large value in mysql db without changing max_allowed_packet Node js waterline orm

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

In order to insert value larger than the max_allowed_packet into mysql, according to mysql docs we can increase max_allowed_packet value from the mysql by using this command `mysql --max_allowed_packet=8M`

Is there any way to that without changing the variable value from the mysql directly. As now my default max_allowed_packet for mysql db is 4MB. But my size of the object is greater than 4MB

I am using sails js sails-mysql waterline orm for updating the value

Here value of processLog is greater than 4MB

```
let logUpdate = await DataLog.update({
          id:id
        }).set({
          logValue: processLog
        });
```

Is there any way from the code I can update value greater than 4MB without changing variable size from mysql.

Now whenever processLog size is greater than 4MB it is giving error as `AdapterError: Unexpected error from database adapter: ER_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`

Comment: You can dynamically change the value of max_allowed_packet otherwise there is no solution to this.